# How to merge fasta sequence if it is split into 2 (or more) records?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bioinformatics, biopython, fasta

I'm working with `fasta` files, where one sequence seems to be split into 2 separate entities.

As example:

```
>SRR6026797.1.1 1 length=251
GGAGTGCCAGCAGCCGCGGTAATACGTAGGTGGCGAGCGTTGTCCGGAATCACTGGGCGTAAAGGGCGCGCAGGCGGCGTGTCAAGTCGGACGTGAAAACCCCTGGCTCAACTGGGGGATGTCGTTCGAAACTGGCATGCTTGAGTGCAGGAGAGGGAAGCGGAATTCCCGGTGTAGCGGTGAAATGCGTAGATATCGGGAGGAACACCAGTGGCGAAGGCGGCTTCCTGGACTGTAACTGACGCTGAGGC
>SRR6026797.1.2 1 length=251
CCGGGAGGACTACAGCGGTATCTAATCCTGTTCGCTACCCACGCTTTCGTGCCTCAGCGTCAGTTACAGTCCAGGAAGCCGCCTTCGCCACTGGTGTTCCTCCCGATATCTACGCATTTCACCGCTACACCGGGAATTCCGCTTCCCTCTCCTGCACTCAAGCATGCCAGTTTCGAACGCCATCCCCCAGTTGAGCCAGGGGTTTTCACGTCCGACTTGACACGCCGCCTGCGCGCCCTTTACGCCCACTC
>SRR6026797.2.1 2 length=251
GGAGTGCCAGCAGCCGCGGTAACACGTAGGGGGCAAGCGTTGTCCGGAATCACTGGGCGTAAAGGGTGCGTAGGCGGTATGTCAAGTCAGGTGTGAAACCCCATGGCTTAACTGTGGGCTTGCACATGAAACTGGCATGCTTGAGTGCAGGAGAGGAAAGCGGAATTCCTAGTGTAGCGGTGAAATGCGTAGATATTAGGAGGAACACCAGTGGCGAAGGCGACTTTCTGGACTGACCCTGACGCTGATGT
>SRR6026797.2.2 2 length=251
CCGGGAGGACTACAAGGGTATCTAATCCTGTTTGCTCCCCACGCTTTCGCACATCAGCGTCAGGGTCAGTCCAGAAAGTCGCCTTCGCCACTGGTGTTCCTCCTAATATCTACGCATTTCACCGCTACACTAGGAATTCCGCTTTCCTCTCCTGCACTCAAGCATGCCAGTTTCATGTGCAAGCCCACAGTTAAGCCATGGGGTTTCACACCTGACTTGACATACCGCCTACGCACCCTTTACGCCCAGTG
```

However, it should be merged as:

```
>SRR6026797.1 1 length=502
GGAGTGCCAGCAGCCGCGGTAATACGTAGGTGGCGAGCGTTGTCCGGAATCACTGGGCGTAAAGGGCGCGCAGGCGGCGTGTCAAGTCGGACGTGAAAACCCCTGGCTCAACTGGGGGATGTCGTTCGAAACTGGCATGCTTGAGTGCAGGAGAGGGAAGCGGAATTCCCGGTGTAGCGGTGAAATGCGTAGATATCGGGAGGAACACCAGTGGCGAAGGCGGCTTCCTGGACTGTAACTGACGCTGAGGCCCGGGAGGACTACAGCGGTATCTAATCCTGTTCGCTACCCACGCTTTCGTGCCTCAGCGTCAGTTACAGTCCAGGAAGCCGCCTTCGCCACTGGTGTTCCTCCCGATATCTACGCATTTCACCGCTACACCGGGAATTCCGCTTCCCTCTCCTGCACTCAAGCATGCCAGTTTCGAACGCCATCCCCCAGTTGAGCCAGGGGTTTTCACGTCCGACTTGACACGCCGCCTGCGCGCCCTTTACGCCCACTC
>SRR6026797.2 2 length=502
GGAGTGCCAGCAGCCGCGGTAACACGTAGGGGGCAAGCGTTGTCCGGAATCACTGGGCGTAAAGGGTGCGTAGGCGGTATGTCAAGTCAGGTGTGAAACCCCATGGCTTAACTGTGGGCTTGCACATGAAACTGGCATGCTTGAGTGCAGGAGAGGAAAGCGGAATTCCTAGTGTAGCGGTGAAATGCGTAGATATTAGGAGGAACACCAGTGGCGAAGGCGACTTTCTGGACTGACCCTGACGCTGATGTCCGGGAGGACTACAAGGGTATCTAATCCTGTTTGCTCCCCACGCTTTCGCACATCAGCGTCAGGGTCAGTCCAGAAAGTCGCCTTCGCCACTGGTGTTCCTCCTAATATCTACGCATTTCACCGCTACACTAGGAATTCCGCTTTCCTCTCCTGCACTCAAGCATGCCAGTTTCATGTGCAAGCCCACAGTTAAGCCATGGGGTTTCACACCTGACTTGACATACCGCCTACGCACCCTTTACGCCCAGTG
```

I wonder, what is the proper way to produce output file with merged sequences (probably, using `biopython`)

My current workaround is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os
from Bio import SeqIO
# pip install biopython
from collections import defaultdict

current_folder = os.path.dirname(__file__)
input_file = os.path.join(current_folder, "input.fasta")
output_file = os.path.join(current_folder, "output.fasta")

records = SeqIO.parse(input_file, "fasta")
records_map = defaultdict(str)

for record in records:
    # kicking out from the end ".1" or ".2" in sequence name
    proper_record_name = ".".join(record.name.split(".")[:-1])
    # if such record exists, expend existing, otherwise : create the new one
    records_map[proper_record_name] += str(record.seq)

with open(output_file, "w") as writer:
    for key in records_map:
        # placeholders based on template from original file and fixed information on the length
        writer.write(f">{key} {key.split('.')[-1]} length={len(records_map[key])}\n")
        # write the glued sequence
        writer.write(f"{records_map[key]} \n")
```

It works, but I don't like processing such data as raw text (not sure if sequences in `input_file` are ordered/organized properly ). Is there a better way?
Thanks!

Comment: I could provide a solution in biopython but are you sure merging the sequences is the right thing to do? I'm guessing these "2 separate entries" are paired end reads

Comment: @Chris_Rands: In this particular case, absolutely.

Comment: can you explain why?

Comment: @Chris_Rands : Because I was specifically asked to do that for a friend)

Comment: I was hoping for a better explanation ;)

Comment: @Chris_Rands could you post your biopython answer ? cant figure out anything shorter with biopython ! Is there a SeqRecord merge function available ?? How would you handle the sorting sequence 1.2.1, 1.2.3, 1.2.2 problem ??